# :target not working in css

Tags: html, css

Hi Friends i am using `:target` in `CSS` following is my code

**CSS**

```
.acco h3 + div{height:0px; overflow:hidden;}
.acco : target h3 + div {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height:100px;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="acco">
<h3>show</h3>
  <div class="test">test</div>

  <div class="click" ><a href="#show">click</a></div>
</div>
```

I am targeting `<div class="test">test</div>` but its not working please help me

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you are missing the `#show` anchor in your markup (and depending on the position) an adaption of the css is necessary (in every case there must not be a space in your pseudoclass `:target`):

```
<div class="acco" id="show">
/* css: no spaces*/
.acco:target h3 + div {

<!-- or -->

<div class="acco">
<h3 id="show">show</h3>

/*css: space between .acco and :target!*/
.acco :target + div {
```

[Demo (first version)](http://jsfiddle.net/mwAfw/)

Comment: Thanks, it works good :) This target styling is new in CSS3 I guess? Or I should feel really ashamed not hearing about it earlier? :D

Comment: @Ms.Nobody Yes it's new with selectors level 3, no reason to feel ashamed, it's so much new stuff, that one can easily get confused. Just if you are interested, there is already selectors api level 4 in work, which has a lot more cool new stuff. I recently posted an answer about that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17400009/1047823 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
.acco:target h3 + div {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height:100px;
}
```

without spaces

Comment: Also the `.acco` div is missing an ID, specifically the ID `show`.

Comment: Can u put it in working fiddle? It ain't working for me.. never seen :target.. always using :hover so I'm quite curious

Comment: @Ms.Nobody it's still missing the anchor. Take a look at the fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The pseudo class that you’re probably most familiar with is `:hover`, which allows you to declare special styling that will be activated when the user mouses over an element. The `:target` pseudo class similarly allows for custom styling that will be activated based on a specific scenario.

`:target` is a pseudo selector like `:hover`, and there should be no space in between.

Good read about it [overhere](http://designshack.net/articles/css/targetcss/)